# Merging SQL views

Tags: sql

I am working for the IT Department of a college as a student worker and have very limited knowledge in using SQL (I am not majoring in Computer Science/Engineering). I'll try my best to describe what I want to accomplish here.

I want to create a table that includes info about new students, basically : id, first name, last name, need  exams (Y/N), Course101 section, instructor.

My problem is, exchange and transfer students and also some first year students would not have to/did not sign up for Course101, so using `WHERE studnt_course = 'Course101%'` will leave out those students. I would like to pick up those students in my view and display their Course101 section, Instructor values as Null.

I am thinking about making two views, one for all new students, and one for students with Course101 only, and do some kind of merging/union but not sure how to actually do that.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: not sure how to do what? Make the views or combine them with `union`?

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17796909/edit) your question and add table(s) schema, sample data and desired output to illustrate your question.

Comment: I am fine with any methods. Just want to figure out an algorithm. Again, the thing I want to accomplish here is to pick up students without Course101 and display their instructor and section values as Null.

Comment: Also which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's still a bit vague what the current tables actually look like which makes it hard to give a good suggestion.

Based on what you've given us I'd suggest looking into a `LEFT INNNER JOIN` which would put `NULL` where the two tables don't overlap.

If you are interested in learning database design (rather than just solving this particular problem) I'd suggest looking into proper database design.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, JBarberU! I finally figured out that a Full Outer Join would work in this case because of the structures of the data and tables.

Answer (score 0):

Create two queries. One for the 101 students and one for the overseas/transfers (you will need to work out what the WHERE clause if for that)
Get each one working to your satisfaction.

If every thing is the same apart from the WHERE clause then:
Then grab the conditions for each, wrap them in brackets and put an OR in between, put that into one query 
So something like:

```
SELECT Name, Id,ShoeSize
FROM Students   
WHERE (studnt_course = 'Course101%') OR (transferred = 1 OR is_exchange = 1)
```

i.e., So all students `WHERE <this> OR <that>` is true

Other wise (e.g., using diffrent tables):
Make sure that you are selecting the same column names in you SELECT statement
If one column has the same info but is call some thing different you can go:

```
 <columnName> AS <NameYouWantToCallIt>
```

Make sure the column names are in the same order.
Then put the word UNION in-between the two queries.

This will combine the results from both queries (and remove duplicates).

```
SELECT Name, Id, ShoeSize
FROM Students   
WHERE studnt_course = 'Course101%'

UNION

SELECT Name, Id, FootSize AS ShoeSize
FROM exchangeStudents   
WHERE transferred = 1 OR is_exchange = 1
```